# XAMPP Virtual host - Error 403 Access denied

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have problem with XAMPP. I install new XAMPP and add this to httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vanessa/public"
ErrorLog "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vanessa/_logs/vanessa.ps-error_log"
CustomLog "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vanessa/_logs/vanessa.ps-access_log" common
ServerAlias www.vanessa.ps
ServerName vanessa.ps
</VirtualHost>
```

and add to etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 vanessa.ps
```

When I open my website: http://vanessa.ps
i have error:

Access denied!

You do not have permission to access the requested directory. There is no index in the catalog or the catalog is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, contact your administrator.

```
Error 403

vanessa.ps
Apache / 2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL / 1.1.1c PHP / 7.3.9 mod_perl / 2.0.8-dev Perl / v5.16.3
```

How can I repair it?

i have MacOS Mojave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid 403 error for image URLs in (local) Wordpress via XAMPP on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502782/how-to-avoid-403-error-for-image-urls-in-local-wordpress-via-xampp-on-windows)

Comment: Yes, but I have MacOS - not Windows. Sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Virtual Host, access forbidden. Using XAMPP OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606234/apache-virtual-host-access-forbidden-using-xampp-os-x)

Comment: Try read your error file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vanessa/_logs/vanessa.ps-error_log" for further clues.